# boost shared ptr makes copy when changing undelying object?

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, refcounting

Does `boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr` makes a copy when

```
*ptr.get() = 5;
```

suppose, the `refcount` was `3`, after the line above will it stay `3` ? or what will happen? will the new *object* be allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't copy, because then the object would no longer be shared.

Also, no need for explicit call to `get()`:

```
*ptr = 5;
```

This has no effect on refcount.

(To create a new shared object: `ptr = boost::make_shared<int>(5)`)

Comment: so I can change the value of underlying object without effecting  refcount? just all objects that point to `boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr` will still point to `boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr`, just the value it holds will be different, right ?

Comment: Yes, @Oleksandra, my answer isn't going to change. For what it's worth, it's exactly the same as with regular pointers (`int*`) in this respect.